# Angular ngRx Dispatch Second Action with data from First Action

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

im working in Angular 13 project and i use ngRx store, i have the following effects that works fine :

```
searchEnterpriseEffect: Observable<Action> = createEffect(

    () => this.effectActions.pipe(

        ofType(EnterpriseActionsTypes.SEARCH_ENTERPRISE),

        switchMap((action: EnterpriseActions) => {

            return this.enterpriseService.getEnterpriseById(action.payload)
                .pipe(
                    map((enterprise) => new SearchEnterpriseActionSuccess(enterprise)),

                    catchError((err) => of(new SearchEnterpriseActionError(err.status)))
                )
        })
    )
);
```

my issue is that i want to get the enterprise object Id after SearchEnterpriseActionSuccess finish then dispatch a new store action called SearchDemandeData(enterpriseId) that takes the data from state returned by previous action.

do you have any idea please how i can do this correctly.

Regards.

Comment: Create other effect that listens to `SearchEnterpriseActionSuccess` , extract the id and dispatch the new action `SearchDemandeData`

Comment: @akotech thanks for you suggestion. could you add i as an answer so i could accept it as the right one.

Comment: just added the answer. glad to have helped 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create other effect that listens to `SearchEnterpriseActionSuccess`, extract the id from the enterprise and dispatch the new action `SearchDemandeData` with the extracted id.

I don't know your exact implementation, but it should be something similar to the following.

```
searchDemandeOnEnterpriseSuccessEffect: Observable<Action> = createEffect(

  () => this.effectActions.pipe(

    // filter by SearchEnterpriseActionSuccess
    ofType(EnterpriseAPIActionsTypes.SEARCH_ENTERPRISE_SUCCESS),

    // map the action to SearchDemandeData Action using the enterprise id
    map((action: SearchEnterpriseActionSuccess) => 
      (new SearchDemandeData(action.enterprise.id))
    )

  )

);
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning a map, returns a switchMap. Now it will expects either and Observable or an Array, and inside the array you can dispatch as many actions as you want.

```
switchMap((enterprise) => [
  new SearchEnterpriseActionSuccess(enterprise),
  new SearchDemandeData(enterpriseId)
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass along the properties to the next action:

```
searchEnterpriseEffect: Observable<Action> = createEffect(

    () => this.effectActions.pipe(

        ofType(EnterpriseActionsTypes.SEARCH_ENTERPRISE),

        switchMap((action: EnterpriseActions) => {

            return this.enterpriseService.getEnterpriseById(action.payload)
                .pipe(
//                           grab the action's payload and add it to the next action 
                    map((enterprise) => new SearchEnterpriseActionSuccess(enterprise, action.payload)),

                    catchError((err) => of(new SearchEnterpriseActionError(err.status)))
                )
        })
    )
);
```

Comment: thanks for your response. could you please provide  an example of how to dispatch correctly my second action "SearchDemandeData(action.payload)"  after grabbing the action payload